# KDB: How to Convert DateTime to Formatted String?

Tags: string, datetime, format, kdb

I want to create a function in KDB that can convert a datetime object to a string based on the user inputted format of the string. Is there a way to do this in KDB?

In Python, it would be something like this:

```
format = "%m-%d-%Y_%H%M%S"
def f(format, dt):
  return dt.strftime(format)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library [datetimeQ](https://github.com/aa1024/datetimeQ) has some functionality for doing this as it isn't inbuilt into kdb.

Example functions included are:

```
q).dtf.format["yy-mm-dd hh:uu:ss.000"; 2018.06.08T01:02:03.456]  
"18-06-08 21:02:03.456"

q).dtf.format["d mmmm, dddd ,yyyy"; 2018.06.18];
"18 June, Tuesday ,2018"

q).dtf.format["d/m/yyyy"; 2018.06.08]
"8/6/2018"
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, [qdate](https://code.kx.com/developer/libraries/date-parser/) is available for datetime parsing and string conversation